# How to extract absolute URL from relative HTML links using Jsoup?

Tags: java, url, jsoup

I am using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to extract URL of an webpage. The `href` attribute of those URL's are relative like:

```
<a href="/text">example</a>
```

Here is my attempt:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements results = document.select("div.results");
Elements dls = results.select("dl");
for (Element dl : dls) {
    String url = dl.select("a").attr("href");
}
```

This works fine, but if I use

```
String url = dl.select("a").attr("abs:href");
```

to get the absolute URL like `http://example.com/text`, it is not working. How can I get the absolute URL?

Comment: Where's the example html? We can't help you by guessing....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need [`Element#absUrl()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String url = dl.select("a").absUrl("href");
```

---

You can by the way shorten the select:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements links = document.select("div.results dl a");
for (Element link : links) {
    String url = link.absUrl("href");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`String url = dl.select("a").absUrl("href");`

Is not correct because `dl.select("a")` will not return a single item but a collection.
You need to get elements by index

eg :

```
Elements elems = dl.select("a");
Element a1 = elems.get(0); //0 is the index first element increasing to (elems.size()-1)
now you can do
a1.absUrl("href");
```

If you are sure only one item will result from the select above, or that the item you want will be the first, you can:

```
String url = dl.select("a").get(0).absUrl("href");
```

Which is also same as

```
String url = dl.select("a").first().absUrl("href");
```

It doesn't have to be the first element anyway, you can always replace  the 0 in 
`String url = dl.select("a").get(0).absUrl("href");` with the index of your element.
Or use a select that is more specific that will only result in one element.