# java: find RSS file(s) of a website

Tags: java, rss

I am writing a java application; using [Rome](https://rome.dev.java.net/) lib for reading RSS feeds of a RSS file of a website. I can read and manage feeds using Rome but I can not find the exact URL path of RSS file. I know there is a line like this in html file specifying the RSS xml file url:

`<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="/rss.ashx" title="Rss feed for yourdomain.com" />`

what is a clean way to find RSS file, url path in java?

thank you all

Comment: Maybe that is relevant for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144529/how-to-extract-absolute-url-from-relative-html-links-using-jsoup

Answer (score 3):

You could use a xpath expression on the html page to get the `<link />`-Node and extract the `href` attribute. Out of the box this will only work on wellformed XHTML pages. Maybe you need to fix the document before applying the xpath.

Or you use something like http://jsoup.org/