# How to extract absolute URLs from a webpage?

Tags: java, url, html-parsing

I am trying to get all URLs in a HTML Webpage. I have written this function

```
public static List<String> getURLs(String url){
        List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
              Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://"+url)
                      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .timeout(20000)
                        .get();

              String bodyHTML= doc2.select("body").get(0).html();
              Pattern pattern =
                    Pattern.compile("(<a [^>]*href=['\"]?|<img[^> ]* src=['\"]?)");

                    Matcher matchs = pattern.matcher(bodyHTML);
                   while( matchs.find()){
                     System.out.println("Match Found "+bodyHTML.substring( matchs.start(), matchs.end()));
                    urls.add(bodyHTML.substring( matchs.start(), matchs.end()));
                    }
                   return urls;



          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }finally
          {
              return urls; 
          }


    }
```

I want to access the pages referred to by these URLs. BUt some of the URLs extracted might be relative. Is there an easy way to find whether a URL is absolute? and if not How can I create one , considering I have a base URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
String bodyHTML = doc2.select("body").absUrl("href");
```

Check [this](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl%28java.lang.String%29) out.

Taken the help from the [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144529/how-to-extract-absolute-url-from-relative-html-links-using-jsoup)

Comment: absURL() function is the way to go but this code is not correct.

Comment: I used this code Elements links=doc2.select("a");
        for(int k=0;k<links.size();k++)
        {
         String tempURL=links.get(k).attr("abs:href");
         if(tempURL.contains(url))
          urls.add(tempURL);
        
         
        }